# CSS - Prevent popup from getting hidden behind other elements on page

Tags: html, css, popup, hidden

A have a popup div. But on popup it is getting hidden behind other elements on the page. How can I ensure that the popup div always stays on top of other elements on page?

Comment: is this a issue on all browsers?

Comment: @Saumitra post some code , it would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the css `z-index` is higher than the others.

(Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)

Comment: i have not set the z-index of other elements, so what value should I use for z-index of popup div .

Comment: @Saumitra Try setting the z-index of the popup element anyway. (Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

Comment: for a comprehensive look at it: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Comment: thanks...that's exactly what I wanted...accepting answer in 9 minutes :)

Comment: @paulslater19 +1 for raising that point , people only use z-index without positioning the element.

Comment: Also note, some elements (like videos) will always render on top in some cases.  You might need to hide these elements first.  Also, IE7 has a different way of thinking about z-index which can cause problems.

Answer (score 1):

To make your popup appear over another element you should make sure that z-index property for the front element must be greater than the one which should get behind

```
//this id element will get at front
#front {
    z-index:2;
}
//this id element will be behind #front element
#back {
    z-index:1;
}
```